# Connecting to Mongo DB atlas via Monk

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, monk

Anyone know how I can fix this

`failed to connect to server [DB_CLUSTER] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

I am using Monk to connect to Mongo Atlas

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk(
  `Connection String is here`
);
db.then(() => {
  console.log('connection success');
}).catch((e) => {
  console.error({ e });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my version of Monk fixed this issue